# Get the type guard type from a type guarded function

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

How do I assign the generic type parameter for a function to a typeguard type from a function's typeguard? Is there some sort of typescript `TypeguardType<matcher>` helper to assist with this?

Something like this:

```js
function findAnimal<TAnimal = TypeguardType<matcher>>(animals: Array<any>, matcher: (animal: any) => boolean) {
    return animals.find(matcher) as TAnimal;
}
```

Here's a full example with usage.

```js
class Dog {
    bark() { }
}
class Cat {
    meow() { }
}
function isDog(animal): animal is Dog {
    return !!animal.bark;
}
function isCat(animal): animal is Cat {
    return !!animal.meow;
}

/**
 * Return the first animal where the matcher evaluates to true
 */
function findAnimal<TAnimal>(animals: Array<any>, matcher: (animal: any) => boolean) {
    return animals.find(matcher) as TAnimal;
}
const animals = [new Dog(), new Cat()];

//what I have to do (explicitly define a generic parameter)
const dog1 = findAnimal<Dog>(animals, isDog);

//what I want to do (typescript infer the return type from typeguard of matcher)
const dog2 = findAnimal(animals, isDog);
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL2aVw) meet your needs?  Note that `find()` is not guaranteed to succeed, so the return type will necessarily include `undefined` unless you want to assert somewhere that it isn't.  Anyway if that works for you I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. I had no idea it was that simple.

Comment: Okay I'll write this up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type inside a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to give you the behavior you're looking for:

```
function findAnimal<T>(animals: any[], matcher: (animal: any) => animal is T) {
  return animals.find(matcher)
}
// function findAnimal<T>(
//  animals: any[], matcher: (animal: any) => animal is T
// ): T | undefined
```

That returns `T | undefined` because [the `find()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) isn't guaranteed to succeed, so it either returns a `T` on success or `undefined` on failure.  Anyway, let's test it:

```
const dog = findAnimal(animals, isDog);
// const dog: Dog | undefined;
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNaAjMAnA1gBQCUq0AvmpaJDAMJgAuqG0AtgKbwDuJZllAGYBXAHbBGAS3ijokiAkSEwoyWzAgAXNBUBPYtpVqNcmIpaZcHRsNyyAhPaPqQAOhwEA3FTQjxUmVMGRmVVF0NRfQjjEFNoYItoKxs7aEdnDVdOHm9KXzEJaVlBSVEAEwBBMI0AHgAVAD5QmIgI3QBtAF0AGnYmYAALDlxtZvCdSNIAXgaJmLi60nRLa1tZDJAIVxLywnVGQeHiKm8AelPoP0LAncrqkHqmjdaJjp6+g6GR6DGNNunZhsFgZoHVoAAfaBiMocHYcMpoNDAGQQZjPaBTaDtUQcbhwJAkXo4vHBEidbxIlHMMpIDGXUp3GK-Ta9eSKYhnC7I0So6A0xDacyQ6Gw0rwn6MIbQZFsAAOkhAwz58A4EFEAHJmPhRDxoJKmHqvhw4gAqGE7SSMDggXQmnT45ClQ0GvC4MD6NBAA)

Comment: I had no idea you could use the `is T` inside the typing for a parameter. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!